# Sorting using nested field in ramda.js

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

In the documentation of [sortBy](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#sortBy), it says we can use R.prop to sort an object by it's field. But if I have to sort by a nested field, it does not work. For example R.prop('id.number') does not work.

```
var items = [{id:3},{id:1},{id:2}];
var sorter = R.sortBy(R.prop('id'));
sorter(items)
```

works fine. But if I have a nested structure

```
var items = [{id:{number:3}},{id:{number:1}},{id:{number:2}}];
var sorter = R.sortBy(R.prop('id.number'));
sorter(items)
```

returns me an empty list. I guess there is a correct way of using R.prop that I am not able to figure out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `R.path` for accessing nested properties, so your example would become `R.sortBy(R.path(['id', 'number']))`

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm mistaken, `id.number` itself is being checked as a property, when in fact there is only the property `id`. `R.prop()` only checks one level down - nested structures are beyond its ability, and being asked to look for the property `number` after doesn't work .

The documentation states that `sortBy` accepts a function which takes an element under consideration. The following is tested on the ramda.js REPL and works:

```
var items = [{id:{number:3}},{id:{number:1}},{id:{number:2}}];
var sorter = R.sortBy(function(item) {return item['id']['number'];});
sorter(items)
```

It works by simply looking up the properties in succession.

tl;dr Anonymous functions for the win.