# Ramda sort array of nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ramda.js

I am looking to sort an array of nested object using Ramda. I have an array:

```
const people = [
  { name: 'Emma', data:{ age: 70 }},
  { name: 'Peter', data:{  age: 78 }},
  { name: 'Mikhail', data:{  age: 62 }},
];
```

I want to sort above array using Ramda. I got [this](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?const%20byAge%20%3D%20R.ascend%28R.prop%28%27age%27%29%29%3B%0Aconst%20people%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20%27Emma%27%2C%20age%3A%2070%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20%27Peter%27%2C%20age%3A%2078%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20%27Mikhail%27%2C%20age%3A%2062%20%7D%2C%0A%5D%3B%0Aconst%20peopleByYoungestFirst%20%3D%20R.sort%28byAge%2C%20people%29%3B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%5B%7B%20name%3A%20%27Mikhail%27%2C%20age%3A%2062%20%7D%2C%7B%20name%3A%20%27Emma%27%2C%20age%3A%2070%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20name%3A%20%27Peter%27%2C%20age%3A%2078%20%7D%5D) but it does not work for me.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you checked https://ramdajs.com/docs/ ?

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820811/ramda-find-object-key-by-nested-key-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want to sort by the path `data.age`, you can get the prop `data` from your object using `R.prop` which will give you an object, and then use `R.prop()` again on that object to get the `age` property. To make a function which does this, you can use `R.compose()`:

```js
const byAge = R.ascend(R.compose(R.prop('age'), R.prop('data')));
const people = [
  { name: 'Emma', data:{ age: 70 }},
  { name: 'Peter', data:{  age: 78 }},
  { name: 'Mikhail', data:{  age: 62 }},
];

const peopleByYoungestFirst = R.sort(byAge, people);
console.log(peopleByYoungestFirst);
//=> [{"name":"Mikhail","data":{"age":62}},{"name":"Emma","data":{"age":70}},{"name":"Peter","data":{"age":78}}]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-buL0byPvI/XRDFscnSc/e0q+sLA65O9y+rbF+0O/4FE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

To break down the above compose function, say you have the object `obj`, which is:

```
obj = { name: 'Emma', data:{ age: 70 }}
```

Performing `R.prop('data')(obj)` will give:

```
{ age: 70 }
```

As you are interested in the `age` property of the returned object, you again can run `R.prop('age')` on the above object:

```
R.prop('age')({age: 70})
```

This will give `70`. So above line can be written as:

```
R.prop('age')(R.prop('data')(obj))
^^^^^ f ^^^^^ ^^^^^^ g ^^^^^  ^ x
```

The issue with this function, however, is that it doesn't return a function which we can pass `obj` into to get `70` out of. Currently, it takes the form of `f(g(x))`, by composing it, we can get the form of `(f.g)(x)`, where `f.g` composes the functions `f` and `g` to produce a new function. To compose in Ramda, we can use `R.compose()`:

```
R.compose(R.prop('age'), R.prop('data'))(obj)
```

This can be eta-reduced to remove the `obj` like it is in the example.

This approach can be generalized to:

```js
const {pipe, split, reverse, map, apply, compose, ascend} = R;
const makeSortFn = compose(ascend, pipe(split('.'), reverse, map(R.prop), apply(compose)));

const byAge = makeSortFn('data.age');
const people = [
  { name: 'Emma', data:{ age: 70 }},
  { name: 'Peter', data:{  age: 78 }},
  { name: 'Mikhail', data:{  age: 62 }},
];

const peopleByYoungestFirst = R.sort(byAge, people);
console.log(peopleByYoungestFirst);
//=> [{"name":"Mikhail","data":{"age":62}},{"name":"Emma","data":{"age":70}},{"name":"Peter","data":{"age":78}}]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-buL0byPvI/XRDFscnSc/e0q+sLA65O9y+rbF+0O/4FE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

But instead, I would favour [Ori's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60949594/5648954), which can be genralized much easier by splitting a string:

```
R.sortBy(R.path(path_str.split('.')))
```

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal I believe so, you can take a look at using sortBy instead of compose: [Sorting using nested field in ramda.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36257219)

Comment: can I use `R.compose` on loop? So when I pass `name` it should sort on basis of names and if I pass `data.age` then it should sort on basis of `age`.

Comment: For this I think `R.pipe` may work.  but I am not able to figure it out how to use it in generic way

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal pipe may work for that, but I would suggest using sortBy such as: `R.sortBy(R.path(path_str.split('.')))`. This would return a function which you can pass  an array of objects into, and will sort based on the string path `path_str`.

Comment: A nice explanation, but [`R.path`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#path) is going to be simpler here.

Comment: @ScottSauyet thanks Scott, I agree. I think Ori's approach is much simpler and easier to extend

Answer (score 4):

Use R.path to get the `data.age`:

```js
const sortByYoungest = R.sortBy(R.path(['data', 'age']))

const people = [{"name":"Emma","data":{"age":70}},{"name":"Peter","data":{"age":78}},{"name":"Mikhail","data":{"age":62}}];

const result = sortByYoungest(people);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-buL0byPvI/XRDFscnSc/e0q+sLA65O9y+rbF+0O/4FE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Taking a page from [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60949362/5157454) you can create a reusable `sortByPath` function using R.pipe:

```js
const sortByPath = R.pipe(R.path, R.sortBy)
const sortByYoungest = sortByPath(['data', 'age'])

const people = [{"name":"Emma","data":{"age":70}},{"name":"Peter","data":{"age":78}},{"name":"Mikhail","data":{"age":62}}];

const result = sortByYoungest(people);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-buL0byPvI/XRDFscnSc/e0q+sLA65O9y+rbF+0O/4FE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: `sortByPath = R.pipe(R.path, R.sortBy)` can't be used with 2 arguments at once. When called as `sortByPath(["data", "age"], people)` it will return a function. I suggest changing the definition to `sortByPath = R.useWith(R.sortBy, [R.path, R.identity])`.